# Объединение запросов SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Приветствую, есть 2 таблицы `db_cashin, db_shop` с одинаковыми полями:

[image: mysql table]

Нужно вывести в одном запросе отсортированную по убыванию информацию по ячейке `time` с обеих таблиц и учитывать, что `steamid` = '12345'

З.Ы. Пробовал через UNION, но не получается отсортировать...

Вот мой не получившийся запрос:

```
SELECT amount, tradeofferid, status, time 
FROM db_cashin 
WHERE steamid = '{$steamid}' UNION 
     SELECT amount, tradeofferid, status, time 
     FROM db_shop 
     WHERE steamid = '{$steamid}'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * from (ваш запрос) t order by `time` desc
```

Comment: Выскакивает предупреждение http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1463399078/133036a0/12681037.jpg
и самое плохое, что не выводится ни одна запись с бд

Comment: вы распечатайте ошибки. У вас вернулся false на запрос

Comment: немного вас не понял на счет "распечатайте ошибки"

Comment: `$mysqli->errno` после query

Comment: я забыл  список в селекте (*) поставить :)

Comment: Спасибо, работает, та я как-то сам в суматохе не заметил.